# Trying to optimize a MySQL query that has sub selects

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following sql

```
SELECT c.identity, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.email_address, c.startDate,
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog cll WHERE cll.clientID = c.identity AND cll.type = 2) as loginCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog clv WHERE clv.clientID = c.identity AND clv.type = 10) as viewCount
FROM client c
LIMIT 50;
```

This query takes ~45 seconds to run (and I am going to need to run this without a limit) with client having ~80,000 records and ClientLog having ~430,000 records.

Is there anything I can do to the sub selects to increase the performance of this query besides breaking it into separate query calls?

Comment: Can you provide the `EXPLAIN` plan to the question?

Comment: What indices do you have on the tables? Can you add the tables definitions? And the query execution plan?

Answer (score 1):

Try runnning the `LIMIT 50` against the `client` table earlier

```
SELECT c.identity, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.email_address, c.startDate,
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog cll WHERE cll.clientID = c.identity AND cll.type = 2) as loginCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog clv WHERE clv.clientID = c.identity AND clv.type = 10) as viewCount
FROM (SELECT * FROM client LIMIT 50) c;
```

or gather the client keys and join a little differently

```
SELECT c.identity, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.email_address, c.startDate,
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog cll WHERE cll.clientID = clientkeys.identity AND cll.type = 2) as loginCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog clv WHERE clv.clientID = clientkeys.identity AND clv.type = 10) as viewCount
FROM
(SELECT identity FROM client LIMIT 50) clientkeys INNER JOIN client c USING (identity);
```

You have to control the subselects by giving them as little data as possible. That's why I suggested running `LIMIT 50` before joining to the correlated subqueries.

### UPDATE 2012-06-15 12:18 EDT

Since this is a full join, remove the `LIMIT 50` from your original query:

```
SELECT c.identity, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.email_address, c.startDate,
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog cll WHERE cll.clientID = c.identity AND cll.type = 2) as loginCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(identity) FROM ClientLog clv WHERE clv.clientID = c.identity AND clv.type = 10) as viewCount
FROM (SELECT * FROM client) c;
```

and make sure ClientLog has a decent index for the correlated subqueries

```
ALTER TABLE ClientLog ADD INDEX clientID_type_index (clientID,type);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: This may be useful (maybe) for when the OP wants to use this `LIMIT 50`. But he mentioned he wants to be running the full select, too.

Comment: In addition, it won't help very much if the `ClientLog` is big and there are no useful indices.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **RolandoMySQLDBA** answer, you can avoid having 2 subselects :

```
SELECT c.identity, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.email_address, c.startDate,
 COUNT(CASE cl.`type` WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS loginCount
 COUNT(CASE cl.`type` WHEN 10 THEN 1 END) AS viewCount
 FROM (SELECT * FROM client LIMIT 50)c 
 LEFT JOIN ClientLog cl ON (cl.identity = c.identity)
 GROUP BY c.identity
```